# How to traverse a list in reverse order in Python (index-style: '... in range(...)' only)

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I'm new to Python so I am still getting used to looping in this language. 
So, for example, I have the following code (the element type in the list is array)

```
my_list = [array0, array1, array2, array3]
temp = my_list[-1]
for k in range(len(my_list) - 1, 0):
    temp = temp + my_list[k - 1]
return temp
```

I want to traverse the list from the end of the list and stop at the second element (`k`=`1`), but it looks like the for loop will never be entered and it will just return the initial temp outside the loop. I don't know why. Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid looping with range, just iterate with a for loop as a general advice.

If you want to reverse a list, use `reversed(my_list)`.

So in your case the solution would be:

```
my_list = reversed([array0,array1,array2,array3])
```

That gives you `[array3, array2, ...]`

For omitting the last array from the reversed list, use slicing:

```
my_list = reversed([array0,array1,array2,array3])[:-1]
```

So your code turns to a one liner :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this part by part:

`len(my_list)` is 4. Thus `range(len(my_list)-1, 0)` is the same as `range(3, 0)`, which is `[]` in Python 2. (In Python 3, try `list(range(3, 0))` to see the same empty list.)

If you want a declining range, use a negative step (third argument):

```
range(3, 0, -1)
```

gives `[3, 2, 1]`. It doesn't include `0`, because even for negative steps, the upper bound (second argument) is exclusive, i.e., not part of the result. It seems you've worked around this by initializing the `temp` variable with the last array in `my_list` already before then loop, and then subtracting 1 from the index when using it to access `my_list` contents in the loop.

```
my_list = [array0, array1, array2, array3]
temp = my_list[-1]
for k in range(len(my_list) - 1, 0, -1):
    temp = temp + my_list[k - 1]
return temp
```

would thus probably work.

However, if you need the indices only to access `my_list`, you can get rid of them by directly iterating over the elements of `my_list` in the (here reverse) order you want:

```
my_list = [array0, array1, array2, array3]
temp = empty_array  # Not quite sure what this has to be. (Depends on your array type.)
for array in reversed(my_list):
    temp = temp + array
return temp
```

I'm assuming your arrays are concatenated in the loop. If it's instead an actual addition (NumPy vector addition, for example — though I don't see why the order of addition would matter for that, except maybe for precision, if the values in `my_list` are sorted), use an appropriate zero-element instead of `empty_array`.

You can even get rid of the loop completely. If you want to add your arrays:

```
my_list = [array0, array1, array2, array3]
return sum(reversed(my_list))
```

If you want to concatenate them:

```
from itertools import chain

my_list = [array0, array1, array2, array3]
return list(chain.from_iterable(reversed(my_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse a list in reverse like so:

```
for i in range(len(lis), 0, -1):
    print (i)
```

To stop at the second element edit your range() function to stop at 1:

```
for i in range(len(lis), 1, -1):
        print (i)
```